# Древовидный вывод меню из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Бесконечная страничка, вместо древовидного меню. Таблица в mysql такая

```
id__name____href____pid
1___Hello___hello___0
2___hi______hi______1
3___what____What____0
```

Php код:

```
include('./config.php');
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY pid, id');
$result= mysql_fetch_array($query);

$tree = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $tree[(int) $row['pid']][] = $row;
}

function treePrint($tree, $pid=0) {
    if (empty($tree[$pid]))
        return;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($tree[$pid] as $k => $row) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row['name'];
        if (isset($tree[$row['id']]))
            treePrint($tree, $row['id']);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

treePrint($tree);
```

Comment: А поподробнее?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поинтересоваться?

Сначала цикл заполняется данными.

Потом идет функция с переменными выше, это не хорошо. Повторяться они не должны, нужно как-то разделять переменные функции и внешние переменные.

Далее

```
 foreach ($tree[$pid] as $k => $row) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row['name'];
        if (isset($tree[$row['id']]))
            treePrint($tree, $row['id']); // и нафига нам рекурсия?
        echo '</li>';
    }
```

Так к слову, что написал то и получил :)

ну и $tree[$pid] вообще не нужен, как таковой

Comment: http://snippets.pp.ru/blog/php/9.html - действовал по уроку

Comment: Зачем так усложнять себе жизнь и учиться на примерах, которые не понятны?

попробуй написать просто на циклах. как напишешь напиши в рекурсии и будет счастье.

Answer (score 0):

```
include('./config.php');

function renderMenu() {
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY pid, id');
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $treeArray = array();
    while ($rowMenu = $result) {
        $treeArray[(int)$rowMenu['pid']][] = $rowMenu;
    }
    treePrint($treeArray);
}

function treePrint($tree, $pid=0) {
    if (!is_array($tree[$pid])) {
        return false;
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($tree[$pid] as $k => $row) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row['name'];
        treePrint($tree, $row['id']);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

renderMenu();
```

Как-то так :)